# How a add a XMl node attributes using C#?

Tags: c#, xml, console-application

I need to add a following XML node in XML files.

```
<preference name='phonegap-version' value='cli-5.1.1' />
```

But I am getting like

```
<preference name="'phonegap-version' value='cli-5.1.1'" xmlns="" />
```

I have used the following code in C#.

```
XmlElement preference = doc.CreateElement("preference");
root.AppendChild(preference);
XmlAttribute newAttribute = doc.CreateAttribute("name");
newAttribute.Value="'phonegap-version' value='cli-5.1.1'";
preference.Attributes.Append(newAttribute);
```

Could you please resolve ? 
Thanks in advance...

Comment: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/135000/how-to-prevent-blank-xmlns-attributes-in-output-from-nets-xmldocument

Comment: If you are doing a lot of XML work, i have found the Xml library in Linq a great deal easier to use. XDocument, XElement and XAttribute. Imo (is that allowed on SO?) it clears up the clutter.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you're only creating one attribute (called `name`) then trying to fill it with multiple attributes. You only append that single attribute. Instead, you should create two attributes and append each of them.

```
XmlElement preference = doc.CreateElement("preference");
root.AppendChild(preference);

// create and append the attribute 'name'
XmlAttribute attributeName = doc.CreateAttribute("name");
attributeName.Value = "phonegap-version";
preference.Attributes.Append(attributeName);

// create and append the attribute 'value'
XmlAttribute attributeValue = doc.CreateAttribute("value");
attributeValue.Value = "cli-5.1.1";
preference.Attributes.Append(attributeValue);
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for response. By trying your suggestion. I am getting like this
     <preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-5.1.1" xmlns="" />
I need like this 
<preference name='phonegap-version' value='cli-5.1.1' />

Comment: If you need to remove the namespace attribute (`xmlns`), [there are many ways to do that](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24309268/3190758). Either single or double quotes should be fine for whichever XML handler you're using. Unfortunately, [I'm not sure there is an easy way to change the quote type from double to single](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/222819/save-attribute-value-of-xml-element-with-single-quotes-using-linq-to-xml). Whichever XML handler you're using should be able to handle this type of scenario regardless.

Answer (score 1):

With XDocument, you can try this :

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("doc.xml");
XElement el = new XElement("preference", new Object[] {new XAttribute("name", "phonegap-version"), new XAttribute("value", "cli-5.1.1")});
doc.Add(el);
doc.Save("doc.xml");
```

Answer (score 0):

I found System.Xml.Linq easier to use. Try this:

```
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("yourpath.xml");
        XElement root = doc.Root;
        root.Add(new XElement("preference",
            new XAttribute("name", "'phonegap-version'"),
            new XAttribute("value", "'cli-5.1.1'")));
        doc.Save("yourpath.xml");
```

Answer (score -1):

```
foreach (XmlNodenode in preferance)
{

    // if element already there, it will override
    XmlAttribute newAttr = xdoc.CreateAttribute("value");
    newAttr.Value = "cli-5.1.1";
    node.Attributes.Append(newAttr);
}
```